# getting value of input text from html to mvc

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, textbox, request

I have textbox containing the url. In html it looks like this:

```
<input id="BannerLink1" name="BannerLink1" type="text" value="@ViewBag.baner1_link" />
```

I'm trying to get this value to controller using Request object:

```
baner.Url_link = Request["BannerLink1"];
```

But my controller always see `Request["BannerLink1"]` as empty string. Any guesses what can be wrong?

Comment: Check in the `network` tab in your browser that the input's value actually sent.

Comment: It used to save value in database. When I hardcode some value, like baner.Url_link = "google.com"; it works crrectly.

Comment: Sure. What I mean is that you can check if the input's value sent correctly to the server using [`network` tab](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/resource-loading#view_http_headers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your input-tag inside form tags (`Html.BeginForm()`) to put the value when the form posts.

Comment: Certainly, if you want to post it with your form to a server, when submitting the whole form, then you should put it between form tags. Or do you strive to send it by ajax?

Comment: I used Html.BeginForm and it works.<br>
However now  I have different issue, after using 'new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }' I can't pass other parameters. Anyway thank you :)

Comment: Do you mean passing additional parameters to the server? You can always use the method version with the routeValues parameter for this purpose. Actually, you don't even have to use 'enctype = "multipart/form-data"' if you don't need to pass binary data from your form.